# Transfer the object from client to server

Tags: meteor

I have collected data in object at client side. Now I want to transfer it to server
in order to store in MongoDB. I am trying with $.post command at client side and $.get 
command at server side. But I got error as $ undefined. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Meteor.methods` and `Meteor.call`, see the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/) for more information.

jQuery GET and POST are meant for HTTP, which Meteor isn't using...